# What is format to send a response to an HttpURLConnection.getInputStream() and avoid "Invalid Http Response"?

Tags: java, http

My server sends a response to an `HTTPUrlConnection` in this manner:

```
ServerSocket servSok = new ServerSocket(portNmb);
Socket sok = servSok.accept();
processTheIncomingData(sok.getInputStream());
Writer wrtr = new OutputStreamWriter(sok.getOutputStream());
wrtr.write("<html><body>123 Hello World</body></html>"); // <------- format?
wrtr.flush();
```

the client

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpUTLConnection) url.openConnection();    
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
sendSomeData(conn.getOutputStream());
String mssg = conn.getResponseMessage(); // <----- Invalid Http Response
```

`conn.getResponseCode()` also gives the same "*Invalid http response*."

Comment: If you want to develop an HTTP server from scratch, you must be prepared to read the HTTP specifications. Why do you want to do that? Why not use one of the many HTTP servers available? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: tears of joy. I am so happy. thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree with @JBNizet. HTTP is a very complex protocol. You should use a server.

But if you are writing this for a toy project, here is some code to get you started.
Do not use any of this in production :)

```
    String content = "<html><body>123 Hello World</body></html>";
    Writer wrtr = new OutputStreamWriter(sok.getOutputStream());
    wrtr.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n");
    wrtr.write("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n");
    //assuming content is pure ascii
    wrtr.write("Content-Length: " + content.length() + "\n");
    wrtr.write("Connection: close\n\n");
    wrtr.write(content);
    wrtr.flush();
    //then close the connection, do not reuse the connection
    //as you might not have consumed the full request content
```

Comment: Answer is not correct. 1. You must consume the entire request content: if you don't, the connection will be reset when you close it, and any pending data in flight lost. 2. The line terminator in HTTP is defined as `\r\n`, not `\n`. 3. You can't assume that the number of characters in a `String` equals the number of bytes the `Writer` will put into the stream, so the `Content-length` header here is not necessarily correctly set.